# Какая информация хранится в cookies?

Tags: cookie

Что хранится в куки помимо данных авторизации на сайте? Слышал, что также хранится информация для отслеживания поведения на сайте? Но что именно хранится для отслеживания, координаты движения мышкой по экрану, клики по ссылкам или что-то еще?

Comment: Откройте куки в браузере да посмотрите. Это не тайна за 7 печатями.

Comment: @KAGG Design и как его посмотреть? у меня mozilla

Comment: При открытом сайте нажмите F12, перейдите на вкладку Хранилище и смотрите, что у вас хранится с данного сайта (кроме кук там еще много что есть).

Comment: В куках могут хранится ссылки, на которых переходит пользователь

Comment: @KAGG Design  Открыл, посмотрел, например этот сайт. Там имена __qca _ga _gat  _ym_isad и т.д. домен везде.stackoverflow.com, срок действия, дата последнего доступа. А значения что-то типа t=0Re3429UO6BvbEt2gd2LrlCmn3. И как понять из этого, что хранится в куки? И как с помощью этого можно отследить поведение на сайте?

Comment: _ga - Google Analytis, _ym - yandex metrika. В этом смысле куки хранят информацию для отслеживания поведения на сайте через скрипты Google и Yandex. Остальные куки - данные разработчика, например, хеши авторизации. Никто в здравом уме и твердой памяти не хранит координаты мышки и клики по ссылкам - размера cookie не хватит.

Comment: @KAGG Design Что-то я ничего не понимаю. Причем тут куки на моем компьютере и google analytics с яндекс метрикой? Google analytics и yandex метрика по идее могут отследить поведение любого на сайте просто так, от перехода по ссылкам и установлены они на сайте, а не на моем компьютере. Но причем тут куки с моего компьютера, каким образом происходит отслеживание с помощью куки?

Comment: Так они узнают, что вы - это вы. Ваш IP может смениться, а куки идентифицируют вас как уникального посетителя.

Comment: @KAGG Design ну а что конкретно в ym и gs хранится? Список посещенных url и время посещения?

Comment: Об этом надо спросить Google и Yandex. Но вы же видите, что размер маленький. Скорее всего, это какая-то идентификационная информация. А сама статистика посещения страниц хранится на серверах этих поисковиков.

Comment: @KAGG Design на вопрос, что за информация хранится в куки для отслеживания?  вы писали-откройте куки да посмотрите, это не тайна за 7 печатями. Получается вы сами не знаете? Меня интересует данный вопрос, поскольку в интернете пишут, что с помощью куки отслеживают поведение на сайте. Но как именно это делается, нигде нет нормального описания

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72119/discussion-between-kagg-design-and--).